# Does AWS Application Load balancer still suffers HOL Blocking with clients?

Tags: amazon-web-services, http2

We recently switched to Amazon's new ALBs (Application Load Balancer) and were excited to get the benefits of http2 multiplexing. But it appears that there is still a HOL (Head of line) blocking issues going on.

[image]

The client is able to request the images in parallel but still has to wait for a period of time before it can begin downloading the image. My guess it that because AWS's Application Load Balancer terminates http2 and then talks to the ec2 instances via http/1 creating the HOL delay.

I may be reading this chart wrong, and if so could someone please explain to me why content isn't being downloaded faster, in other words I would expect the green portion to be smaller and the blue bar to appear sooner. Does networking between the load balacner and ec2 instance *not* suffer from HOL? Is there some magic stuff happening?

Comment: That's interesting... Have you asked Amazon if they use HTTP/1.1 to talk to the backend ?

Comment: I have not, but I assume they do since we have nginx on our ec2 boxes without the http2 module.

Answer (score 1):

I believe that what you see might be related to how current Chrome (around v54) prioritizes requests.

#### Exclusive dependencies

Chrome uses HTTP/2's exclusive dependencies (that can be dynamically re-arranged as the page is parsed and new resources are discovered) in order to have all streams depend strictly on one another. That means that all resources are effectively sent one after the other. I wrote a small utility that parses the output of chrome://net-internals/#http2 in order to show the tree for a given page: https://github.com/deweerdt/h2priograph.

A dependency from stream to another can either be exclusive or not. Section 5.3.1 of RFC 7540 covers that part: https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7540#section-5.3.1, here's the example they give when adding a new stream D to A:

Not exclusive:

```
   A                 A
  / \      ==>      /|\
 B   C             B D C
```

Exclusive:

```
                     A
   A                 |
  / \      ==>       D
 B   C              / \
                   B   C
```

#### Example

Let's take this page for example

Chrome only uses the exclusive dependencies, so the dependency tree might at first look like:

```
 HTML
  |
 PNG
  |
 PNG
```

When the javascript is discovered, Chrome reprioritizes it above the images (because the javascript is more likely to affect how the page is rendered), so Chrome puts the JS right below the HTML:

```
 HTML
  |
 JS
  |
 PNG
  |
 PNG
```

Because all the requests are daisy chained, it might look, as in the waterfall you posted that requests are executed one after another like in HTTP/1, but they're not, because they can be re-ordered on the fly *and all the requests are sent to the browser ASAP*.

Firefox on the other hand will have resources of the same type share the same priority so you should be able to see some interlacing there.

Please note that what Chrome does isn't equivalent to what used to happen with HTTP/1 since all the requests have been sent to the server, so the server always has something to be sent on the wire. In addition to that, ordering is dynamic, so if a higher priority resource is discovered in the page, Chrome will re-order the priority tree so that this new resource takes precedence over existing lower priority resources.

Comment: is there any documentation to explain this more? I'm not quite sure I fully understand what you're suggesting. Thanks!

Comment: Chrome's current behavior isn't documented AFAIK. This presentation is very good, http://sssslide.com/speakerdeck.com/summerwind/2-prioritization but Chrome's behavior has changed since, so that part doesn't apply anymore. Is there any specific part I could explain better?

Comment: I'm not sure what "HTTP/2's exclusive dependencies" is. Let me try to explain it back to you to see if you can find the flaw in my understanding.

Chrome sends all the request in parallel but downloads the content 1 by 1 so that it can rearrange prioritization. If Chrome finds something more important based on how the page is parsed or when new resources are discovered it can prioritize that resource first.

Comment: I've updated the post to go into more detail about dependencies, let me know if it helps. I think your description of what happens is correct.

Comment: Thank you for the clarification! I'm going to upvote this answer as helpful but I'm a bit hesitant to mark it as "the correct" answer because this is based on observation of a behavior rather the cold hard facts. I appreciate you taking the time to share your findings!

Answer (score 0):

Might be super late for an answer, but still.

AWS ELB documentation clearly states that:

1. The backend connection (between ALB and target) supports HTTP 1.1 only
2. The backend connection does not support HTTP 1.1 pipelining (which might have somewhat replicated HTTP 2 multiplexing).

So essentially what you observe are multiplexed requests on the frontend connection that are processed one by one by ALB and waiting for backend reply until next frontend request is processed and routed to target.

You can refer to "HTTP connections" section from [documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticloadbalancing/latest/userguide/elb-ug.pdf).